# Userform displaying error that i can't see is wrong

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Userform keeps telling me that this code is wrong, and there is a mistake under "i for addon shape 1,2 and 3 (rectangle). I have tried retying it and doing them with different brackets. they are equations to find the moment of inertia.It is a project to be able to create unique shapes and for a userform to calculate the moment of inertia,bending moment and maximum deflection.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code in these lines:

AddRectangle_I1 = (B1 * H1 ^ 3) / 12

AddRectangle_I2 = ((B2 * (H2 ^ 3)) / 12)

AddRectangle_I3 = (B3 * (H3 ^ 3)) / 12

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()


'I for addon shape 1 (Circle)
Pi = 3.14159
R3 = Stage_2.AddOnA1

AddCircle_I1 = Pi / 4 * R3 ^ 4

'I for addon shape 2 (Circle)
Pi = 3.14159
R4 = Stage_2.AddOnB1

AddCircle_I2 = Pi / 4 * R4 ^ 4

'I for addon shape 3 (Circle)
Pi = 3.14159
R5 = Stage_2.AddOnC1

AddCircle_I3 = Pi / 4 * R5 ^ 4

'I for addon shape 1 (Rectangle)

B1 = Stage_2.AddOnA1
H1 = Stage_2.AddOnA2

AddRectangle_I1 = (B1 * H1 ^ 3) / 12

'I for addon shape 2 (Rectangle)

B2 = Stage_2.AddOnB1
H2 = Stage_2.AddOnB2

AddRectangle_I2 = ((B2 * (H2 ^ 3)) / 12)

'I for addon shape 3 (Rectangle)

B3 = Stage_2.AddOnC1
H3 = Stage_2.AddOnC2

AddRectangle_I3 = (B3 * (H3 ^ 3)) / 12


'I' for addon shape 1 (Triangle)

B4 = Stage_1.AddOnA1
H4 = Stage_1.AddOnA2

AddTriangle_I1 = (B4 * (H4 ^ 3)) / 36

'I' for addon shape 2 (Triangle)

B5 = Stage_1.AddOnB1
H5 = Stage_1.AddOnB2

AddTriangle_I2 = (B5 * H5 ^ 3) / 36

'I' for addon shape 3 (Triangle)

B6 = Stage_1.AddOnC1
H6 = Stage_1.AddOnC2

AddTriangle_I3 = (B6 * H6 ^ 3) / 36

'Calculations 


If AddShape1 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddCircle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Circle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddCircle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Triangle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddTriangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Circle" Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddCircle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Triangle" And AddShape2 = "Rectangle " And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddTriangle_I1 + AddRectangle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Triangle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddTriangle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3

ElseIf AddShape1 = "Rectangle " And AddShape2 = "Circle" And AddShape_3 = "Rectangle " Then
I = Stage_2.Txtin1 + AddRectangle_I1 + AddCircle_I2 + AddRectangle_I3


Else
MsgBox "Error"

End If

Stage_2.txtIn.Value = I

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Stage_2` and its properties e.g `AddOnA1`? Also, you should really dimension your variables. Try adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your code and use e.g. `Dim Pi As Double`

Comment: Also, what's the actual error message and how do you know it's occurring at those lines exactly, does the debugger take you to those lines?